# Stored procedure return a collection complex types object generator tools

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, orm

I wonder if there is any free/open source tools to generate a return collection complex types object from stored procedures, like vs2010 entity framework stored procedures add function import tools.

Regards,
Andrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can found alots helpers can do this for you like http://radstudio.codeplex.com/releases but i dont know why you want to autogenerate all things anyway i recommend try to  use petapoco ORM if you find a easy way for work with data and get a best performance.

http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/ :)

Comment: My Recent project use sqlserver 2000 and subsonic t4 templates, and i want to make all my store procedure return  a collection complex types object. 

Like bellow : 
 
`StoredProcedure xx = DB.aspnet_UsersInRoles_Get_List();
List<userinrole> tt = xx.ExecuteTypedList<userinrole>().ToList();
Gridview1.DataSource = tt;
Gridview1.DataBind();`